# Passing multiple arrays to for each loop..i think

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, foreach

I love jQuery and dont really understand php.

I am making a slider with albums.  So far so good except I am now stuck trying to add two arrays into one for each loop. At least I think that is the best solution.

In my code you can see I have achieved what I need by hard coding 6 images for the 6 custom fields in the custom post type (I am using wordpress).  The problem is that if there are not six images then the slider show a blank image (as it exists but doesnt have a src).  I tried removing the element with jquery but that was no good.  Here is the code I have so far, perhaps there is something i am missing, I just cant seem to get the logic quite right.

```
<?php 

                    $args = array(
                        'post_type'         => 'albums_gallery',
                    );

                    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                    $album_name = get_the_ID();


                    $image_1 = get_field('image_1');
                    $image_1_url = $image_1['url'];
                    $image_1_caption = get_field('image_1_caption');

                    $image_2 = get_field('image_2');
                    $image_2_url = $image_2['url'];
                    $image_2_caption = get_field('image_2_caption');

                    $image_3 = get_field('image_3');
                    $image_3_url = $image_3['url'];
                    $image_3_caption = get_field('image_3_caption');

                    $image_4 = get_field('image_4');
                    $image_4_url = $image_4['url'];
                    $image_4_caption = get_field('image_4_caption');

                    $image_5 = get_field('image_5');
                    $image_5_url = $image_5['url'];
                    $image_5_caption = get_field('image_5_caption');

                    $image_6 = get_field('image_6');
                    $image_6_url = $image_6['url'];
                    $image_6_caption = get_field('image_6_caption');


                ?>
                    <div class="album album_<?php echo $album_name ?>">
                        <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
                            <div class="slider" class="nivoSlider">

                                <!--<img src="<?php echo $image_1['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_1['alt']; ?>" title="<?php echo $image_1_caption; ?>" />
                                <img src="<?php echo $image_2['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_2['alt']; ?>" title="<?php echo $image_2_caption; ?>" />
                                <img src="<?php echo $image_3['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_3['alt']; ?>" title="<?php echo $image_3_caption; ?>" />
                                <img src="<?php echo $image_4['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_4['alt']; ?>" title="<?php echo $image_4_caption; ?>" />
                                <img src="<?php echo $image_5['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_5['alt']; ?>" title="<?php echo $image_5_caption; ?>" />
                                <img src="<?php echo $image_6['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_6['alt']; ?>" title="<?php echo $image_6_caption; ?>" />-->

                                <?php 
                                    $images = array("$image_1_url","$image_2_url","$image_3_url","$image_4_url", "$image_5_url", "$image_6_url");
                                    foreach ($images as $image) {
                                        if ($image != "") {
                                            echo "<img src='";
                                            echo $image;
                                            echo "' ";
                                            echo "title='caption'";
                                            echo "/>";
                                        }
                                    };
                                ?> 

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

I need to add the image caption, and probably a link into the for each and if statements, little out of my depth being a designer.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That’s terrible code. If you need your images as an array – then _add_ them into an array in the first place, instead of using variable names with numbers in them. Suggestion: Don’t use an array, but use a `for` loop  going from 1 to 6, in the place where you want to output the images, and call `get_field` inside the loop by placing the loop counter in the argument string. If that method returns an actual image, output it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all you need

```
<div class = "slider-wrapper theme-default">
    <div class = "slider" class = "nivoSlider">
        <?php

        $images = Array();
        for($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
            $image = get_field("image_{$i}");
            if(!$image || !$image['url']) {
                break;
            }
            $caption = get_field("image_{$i}_caption");
            ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" title="<?php echo $caption; ?>" />
            <?php
        }

        ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, You Da Man!